# SQL query to copy column contingent on contents

Tags: sql

Currently I have an SQL query that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
(Date, Name, Age, City)
SELECT
DATE_ADD (Date, INTERVAL 7 DAY), Name, Age, City
FROM my_table
```

This allows me to carry forward to new weeks with an incrimenting "Date" column, while copying over consistent columns (I have other numerical columns that don't copy over).  However I also have a column called "Status" which I want to copy forward only if the status is "Hold" or "Pending".  If the status is either of those, I want it to carry forward as "Needs Examining".

I know I need some type of if function within my SQL code, but I am uncertain how exactly to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by the `CASE`, if the `Status` is not matching you can add as empty string.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (Date, Name, Age, City, Status)
SELECT DATE_ADD (Date, INTERVAL 7 DAY), Name, Age, City, 
       CASE WHEN Status IN ('Hold', 'Pending') THEN 'Needs Examining'
       ELSE '' END AS Status
FROM my_table
```

Or, if you want to INSERT only for the Hold, Pending status you need to add the condition in the WHERE clause and in the SELECT you can place your required content:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (Date, Name, Age, City, Status)
SELECT DATE_ADD (Date, INTERVAL 7 DAY), Name, Age, City, 'Needs Examining' AS Status
FROM my_table
WHERE Status IN ('Hold', 'Pending')
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks